# Why does state show update before setState is called

Tags: javascript, reactjs

`handleOptions` is a method which is called every time a button is clicked and is passed an options object which it uses to update this.state.options.

```
this.state = {
    options: []
}

handleOptions(options){
    let stat = this.state.options;
    console.log(stat)
    stat.push(options)
    this.setState({ options: stat })
}
```

As you can see I'm logging the previous state options before calling `this.setState` to add it to the state. But for some reason the log output shows the updated state. It logs an empty array the first time as expected but after that it logs the updated state

I also tried passing a function to `this.setState` instead of an object, same result.

```
handleOptions(options){
    this.setState((prevState) => {
        let stat = prevState.options;
        console.log(stat)
        stat.push(options)
        return {options: stat}
    })
}
```

What am I missing???

Comment: i don't believe you are missing anything but the console log doesn't show the result as you expected rather than showing the variable at the time of execution it will show the result updated because after the log you modified the variable 
if you want to see the real value use the google chrome react extension

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) mutates original array. You could use [`concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) instead.

```
handleOptions(options){
    this.setState((prevState) => {
        let stat = prevState.options;
        console.log(stat)
        return {options: stat.concat(options)}
    })
}
```

As of

> But for some reason the log output shows the updated state

Console tries to show you current object state. So if you modify an array using push you will see modified values. If you want to log the value at the very specific moment you could say log a copy `console.log(stat.slice())` or a stringified representation `console.log(JSON.stringify(stat))`